# how to map multiple rows in a single object?

Tags: java, spring

I want to map multiple rows into a single Object. Here is my resultSet

```
Id        Name       Marks
1         A          34
2         b          35
```

My class is something like this:

```
public class student {
    int id;
    String name;
    List <Integer> marks;
}
```

I tried using RowMapper but that is for 1:1 relationship b/w row and object. Please suggest me the right approach to achive this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the example each row has a different `Id` and `Name`, yet your `student` class (which should be **S**tudent), has a single `id` and `name` attribute.  How could multiple rows fit in a single `Student`?

Comment: that was just an example actually there can be same Ids and names. @AndrewS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Nico Van Belle's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42141098/4969410) using `ResultSetExtractor` is a way to go, except you would return `Collection<Student>` instead of a single `Student` object.

When implementing [`ResultSetExtractor<T>`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/ResultSetExtractor.html), Spring gives you the complete ResultSet (all returned rows from DB). It is your responsibility (and freedom) to implement the logic how to extract the data/objects, you would like to return as a (complete) result. And result is a single object, e.g. Set or List (of Student objects).

Here is a rough example:

```
new ResultSetExtractor<Collection<Student>>() {
    @Override
    public Collection<Student> extractData(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException, DataAccessException {
        Map<Integer, Student> studentMap = new HashMap<>();

        while(rs.next()){
            Integer id = rs.getInt(0);
            Student student = studentMap.get(id);

            if (student == null) {
                String name = rs.getString(1);
                student = new Student(id, name); // additional constructor for Student class
                studentMap.put(id, student);
            }

            student.addMark(rs.getInt(3));
        }

        return studentMap.values();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In the case that not every 1 row results in an object, you can use the ResultSetExtractor. Your final solution should resemble this roughly made example;

```
new ResultSetExtractor<Student>() {
    @Override
    public Student extractData(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException, DataAccessException {
        Student student = new Student();
        while(rs.next()){
            // internal logic where you set id, name and add marks to the list
            student.addMark(rs.getInt(3));
        }
        return student;
    }
});
```

Comment: Id       Name       Marks
1        A          34
2        b          35

Comment: I want my ResultSetExtractor to be like 
new ResultSetExtractor<Student>() {
    @Override
    public List<Student> extractData(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException, DataAccessException {
        List<Student> student = new ArrayList<Student>;
        while(rs.next()){
            // internal logic where you set id, name and add marks to the list
  Student s = new Student();
s.setId(rs.getInteger(“id”));s.setName(rs.getString(“name”));
 s.setmarks(new ArrayList<Integer>().add(rs.getmarks(“marks”))); 
            
        }
        return student;
    }
});

Comment: If I go with your approach everytime I have to search with studentId in the List and update the mark list with the new obtained marks in the current rs. That doesn't looks good to me. Is there anyother that I can follow??@Nico Van Belle

Comment: Well.. without you posting a query it's hard to know what Id Name Marks represents. Is it returning marks of 1 student or marks for a set of students? If you are returning 1 mark per row and expect multiple marks per student in the resultset then the right approach would still be using a ResultSetExtractor instead of a RowMapper.